# Amazon Alexa Service Simulator is not sending POST data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, service, simulator, amazon-echo

I'm trying to build a .NET web api that will be invoked by Amazon's Alexa service (Echo). However, the Alexa Service Simulator at developer.amazon.com does not seem to be sending the POST data.  I'm using the "Failed Request Tracing" feature of IIS to troubleshoot the HTTP POST requests that are being sent via the Service Simulator and the log files show that the HTTP requests sent from the Alexa Service Simulator are coming in on port 443, but the HTTP POST data is completely empty. The POST data should contain the "amazon echo service request" object as a JSON string, but it doesn't. When I make the HTTP POST request via Fiddler the POST data contains the "amazon echo service request" object as a JSON string and my .NET web api works perfectly. Has anyone else had this problem with the Alexa Service Simulator? What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: What does your endpoint string look like?  https://...

Comment: Hi Daniel! Any additional information you could share will be a big help in tracing down your issues: Does the issue happen when you're using the "Text" request, or the "JSON" request? If you're using the Text request, what is shown in the Service Request input box? If using the JSON request, what is the content of your JSON Request input box? Any links to screenshots are a big help, and feel free to reach out on the Alexa forums for additional support!  http://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/category.jspa?categoryID=48

Answer (score 1):

I was using the JSON Request input box because I needed to manually add the accessToken property to the service request object. This is what was causing my problem. Once I removed the accessToken property and changed my web service to not require an accessToken I was able to get the Simulator to work. I will revisit the accessToken stuff next week.

Answer (score 0):

In my case - a mild case of RTFM - I forgot to start my skill with the invocation phrase, although it clearly states so in the user-interface:

> First, open your skill with your invocation name. Then start testing your dialog.

It took me some time to realize what I was doing wrong ;)